# Get all required fields of a nested Pydantic model

Tags: python, python-3.6, pydantic

My nested Pydantic model is defined as follows:

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Location(BaseModel):
    city: Optional[str]
    state: str
    country: str


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str = "Gandalf"
    age: Optional[int]
    location: Location
```

I would like to get all required fields for the `User` model.
For the above example, the expected output is `["id", "state", "country"]`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: but with a flat list as an output is not clear that state and country belong to the nested 'location' item

Comment: would it be acceptable to have a list of key:value pairs ?

Comment: @farbiondriven a flat list is preferable since I would like to match this list against another list.

Comment: @farbiondriven Key value pairs are also fine, thank you

Comment: `name` is not a required field though. If a field has a default value, it is not required. In your case `User.name` has the default value `"Gandalf"`.

Comment: My bad, let me fix the above code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with a generator function.

---

### UPDATE: Pydantic `v2`

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator
from pydantic import BaseModel


def required_fields(model: type[BaseModel], recursive: bool = False) -> Iterator[str]:
    for name, field in model.model_fields.items():
        if not field.is_required():
            continue
        t = field.annotation
        if recursive and isinstance(t, type) and issubclass(t, BaseModel):
            yield from required_fields(t, recursive=True)
        else:
            yield name
```

**Important note**:

Starting with version `2.0` Pydantic (thankfully) made its treatment of fields of type `T | None` (or `Optional[T]`) consistent with all other types. This has **backwards-incompatible** implications, particularly regarding what fields are considered **required**.

This change is documented [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/migration/#required-optional-and-nullable-fields), but the short version is that a field is now considered required, if and *only* if a default value was explicitly defined for it. (Assigning the `Ellipsis`/`...` to it in a model definition still [makes it required](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.3/usage/models/#required-fields), but does not constitute setting a default.) This means a field typed `Optional[T]` will have **no implicit default** value of `None` anymore.

Using your example above, those models have more required fields in Pydantic `v2` than in Pydantic `v1`. In fact, the only non-required field is `User.name`.

Demo:

```py
print(list(required_fields(User, recursive=True)))
```

Output:

```
['id', 'age', 'city', 'state', 'country']
```

If you wanted to migrate to `v2` and achieve the same behavior with those models, you would have to specify the `None` default for the relevant fields like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional


class Location(BaseModel):
    city: Optional[str] = None
    state: str
    country: str


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: Optional[str] = "Gandalf"
    age: Optional[int] = None
    location: Location
```

Using the same generator will now yield the expected output:

```
['id', 'state', 'country']
```

---

### Original: Pydantic `v1`

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator
from pydantic import BaseModel


def required_fields(model: type[BaseModel], recursive: bool = False) -> Iterator[str]:
    for name, field in model.__fields__.items():
        if not field.required:
            continue
        t = field.type_
        if recursive and isinstance(t, type) and issubclass(t, BaseModel):
            yield from required_fields(t, recursive=True)
        else:
            yield name
```

Using the models you defined in your example, we can demonstrate it like this:

```py
print(list(required_fields(User, recursive=True)))
```

Output:

```
['id', 'state', 'country']
```

---

### UPDATE: Caveat

Regardless of the Pydantic version, this recursion no longer works, if the type of a field is a **union** between a model and another type.

In fact, the expected behavior at that point is not well defined. Say your `User` model instead looked like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union


class Location(BaseModel):
    ...


class User(BaseModel):
    ...
    location: Union[Location, int]
```

Which fields are now required exactly? Technically, you can initialize a `User` now by just passing an integer for `location` (e.g. `User(..., location=1)`), which would mean none of the `Location` model fields would be required. But if you wanted to assign a `Location` instance to it, then its required fields *would* be required for a `User` as well.

This may seem like a contrived example, but it is pretty common to have for example unions of different models as field types, which causes the same problem. Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union


class LocationA(BaseModel):
    ...
    state: str
    country: str


class LocationB(BaseModel):
    ...
    latitude: str
    longitude: str


class User(BaseModel):
    ...
    location: Union[LocationA, LocationB]
```

Again, it is unclear, which sub-fields exactly should be considered required as you defined it in your question. The technical answer given by Pydantic of course is *those that are required by **either** of the sub-models*. But it is unclear how this can be properly expressed in a simple list of field names.

My solution above will therefore simply not even look for nested fields, if it encounters a union, but simply return the `location` name, unless a default is set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I wanted